# How to correctly pronounce 'presentation'?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, british-english

I have been confident with my pronunciation of the word `presentation`, which is `/prɛz(ə)nˈteɪʃ(ə)n/` or `/ˌprez.ən'teɪ.ʃən/`.

In the Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary, the pronunciation of this word is as above in both AmE and BrE. I also listen to the human pronunciation given by the dictionary and decide that it must be `/ˌprez.ən'teɪ.ʃən/`. Also, on [http://dictionary.cambridge.org](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/presentation), both AmE and BrE versions are pronounced as `/prez.ən'teɪ.ʃən/`.

However, on the Oxford Learner's Dictionaries ([http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/presentation?q=presentation%20)), this word is pronounced as BrE `/ˌpreznˈteɪʃn/`, AmE `/ˌpriːzenˈteɪʃn/` with the human pronunciation being clearly different.

So my questions:

1. Why do the two 'reliable' dictionaries give different versions of pronunciation of `presentation`?
2. Are both right? Which is more common?

Comment: Isn't it simply a case of "British *prez-en-tation*, American *pree-zen-tation*"?

Comment: Why are you paying attention to British dictionaries when trying to figure out whether a variant pronunciation in American English pronunciation?  [All](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/presentation) [three](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=presentation) [American](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/presentation) dictionaries I checked indicate that both pronunciations are acceptable.

Comment: Actually, Cambridge gives _/ˌprez·ənˈteɪ·ʃən, ˌpriˌzen-/_ for US pronunciation if you click on the _American_ tab.

Comment: I hear both versions, and while the short E version is likely more common (here in the Midwest US), the long E version is fairly common as well.

Comment: What is your question? Can a word such as "presentation"  have two different,   correct pronunciations–even in the same country? The answer is yes. As a native speaker of American English, I use /prez/ and the /priz/ variant seems odd, but we don't all speak the same.

Comment: You guys seem to miss my points. What I mean is learners of English in their non-speaking countries depend on dictionaries to learn English. But Cambridge says only `/ˌpreznˈteɪʃn/` for both AmE and BrE while Oxford teaches them that `/ˌpreznˈteɪʃn/` is BrE and `/ˌpriːzenˈteɪʃn/` is AmE.

Comment: Also, why down-voted me? I don't think you put yourself in English learners' shoes when you give comments. A typical learner of English as a foreign language would be very confused with this inconsistency.

Comment: Relevant blog post about the tendencies for pronouncing the vowels in the prefixes *pre-, re- and de-*: http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.com/2010/04/re.html?m=1

Comment: A learner might well be confused by the inconsistency in pronunciation. The inconsistency is there because it is there: different speakers pronounce the word differently. (That's a clue that you can pronounce it either way.)

Comment: @NiamhDoyle - Have you ever gotten very far into Spanish?  There are several dialects in Spain alone, and Spanish Spanish has significant differences from New World Spanish.

Comment: there are many free online 'enunciators'.

Answer (score 3):

Some answers to your questions:

1. Why do the two 'reliable' dictionaries give different versions of pronunciation of presentation?

Who told you that these were "the two 'reliable' dictionaries"? These are both British dictionaries, and both seem to treat American pronunciations more or less as a side issue; they don't always get them correct. They are very reliable for the definitions of the words (at least the British English definitions, which are the same for most words as the American definitions) and the British pronunciations.

2. Are both right? Which is more common?

Two of the American dictionaries I checked (*[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/presentation) and [American Heritage](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=presentation)*), say that both /ˌprezənˈteɪʃən/ and /ˌpriːzənˈteɪʃən/ are acceptable pronunciations. I hear both. So for this particular word, these American dictionaries are batting 1000, while the British dictionaries are not. Unfortunately, neither of them gives pronunciations in IPA.

Which is more common? That may depend on which region of the U.S. that you live in, and I wouldn't want to guess the answer without access to a nation-wide survey.

Comment: For what it’s worth, in a 2007 update for *presentation* the OED gives  Brit. /ˌprɛznˈteɪʃn/,  U.S. /ˌprɛznˈteɪʃ(ə)n/, /ˌpriˌzɛnˈteɪʃ(ə)n/, /ˌpriznˈteɪʃ(ə)n/. I can’t say that the /priz/ pronunciation personally rings any bells; I’ve only ever said /prɛz/. I can’t imagine anyone in the world ever saying /prez/ like *prays*.

Answer (score 1):

> Why do the two 'reliable' dictionaries give different versions of pronunciation of presentation?

Because English speakers pronounce the word in different ways.

> Are both right? Which is more common?

Yes, both are right. I don't know which is more common. But if you  choose a pronunciation from a reliable dictionary, there should be no problem. If you chat  with other speakers and hear them pronounce the word differently from you, then maybe you can change the way you pronounce it. Reliable dictionaries won't give you bad pronunciations. You can also check forvo.com and listen to various native pronunciations.

It is also simply not true that, to quote part of your comment,

> learners of English in their non-speaking countries depend on dictionaries to learn English.

Maybe you do. Most learners I know rely on more natural sources, such as podcasts, forvo, speaking with native speakers on Italki, Verbling, GoSpeaky, etc., YouTube videos such as Rachel's English, listening to English radio, watching movies, etc. Yes, you can start by consulting a dictionary, but you should rely more on these other sources if you're truly studying and learning the language. And I haven't even mentioned taking English classes or hiring a tutor. Okay, now I have mentioned them.